# Receiving this warning or message at boot-up time [ pnp 0.01 can't evaluate_CRS:12311 ] in Linux Ubuntu20.04

Tags: boot, reboot

I couldn't find any solution or guidance, It will be highly appreciated if anybody can tell me about it. Thank you in anticipation.

[Edit]
Partial output of command - **$sudo dmesg**

```
[    0.172242] pnp 00:01: can't evaluate _CRS: 12311
[    0.172247] fbcon: Taking over console**

[    0.172348] system 00:03: [io  0x1854-0x1857] has been reserved
[    0.172502] system 00:04: [io  0x0a20-0x0a3f] has been reserved
[    0.172504] system 00:04: [io  0x0a10-0x0a1f] has been reserved
[    0.172626] system 00:07: [io  0x04d0-0x04d1] has been reserved
```

Comment: Does it prevent booting? If not then ignore it. It's something to do with ACPI so you may try to update UEFI ("BIOS"). It may or may not "fix" it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your attention, No it is not preventing boot. I'll ignore it from now on.

Comment: Now my WiFi is losing signals from the DSL modem, should it be due to the above error?

Pasting the partial output of command - $ sudo dmesg

Output:

[    0.172104] system 00:00: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff] has been reserved

[    0.172242] pnp 00:01: can't evaluate _CRS: 12311
[    0.172247] fbcon: Taking over console

[    0.172348] system 00:03: [io  0x1854-0x1857] has been reserved
[    0.172502] system 00:04: [io  0x0a20-0x0a3f] has been reserved
[    0.172504] system 00:04: [io  0x0a10-0x0a1f] has been reserved